# How to get a 'dobj' in spacy

Tags: spacy

In the following Tweet spacy [dependency tagger](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Juniper%20Research%3A%20AI%20start-ups%20set%20to%20disrupt%20healthcare%20market%2C%20with%20%24800%20million%20to%20be%20spent%20on%20CAD%20Systems%20by%202022&model=en&cpu=1&cph=1) states that disrupt (VB) is a dobj of healthcare market (NN). As these two terms are connected I would like to extract them as one phrase. Is there any way to navigate the parse tree so I can extract the dobj of a word? If I do the folllowing I get market but not 'heathcare market'

```
from spacy.en import English
from spacy.symbols import nsubj, VERB,dobj

nlp = English()
doc = nlp('Juniper Research: AI start-ups set to disrupt healthcare market, with $800 million to be spent on CAD Systems by 2022')

for possible_subject in doc:
if possible_subject.dep == dobj:
    print(possible_subject.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as below using noun chunks

```
for np in doc.noun_chunks:
    if np.root.dep == dobj:
        print(np.root.text)
        print(np.text)
```

Comment: How to display the VERB?